Encryption over data relations in Postgres
I'm working on a system containing user data. I'm using Postgres as my main DB and all user-related data in the system are related to their owner user using foreign keys directly or in relation tables. This foreign key and reference to owner user entity is quite important to me for querying and collecting reports over my data. But my problem here is to keep user-related data secure and make it undetectable to check which data is related to my owner user. What I need is a way to encrypt the foreign key relating the user to their data. I've already reached this point to use Postgres encryption extensions to encrypt the foreign key itself with a secret key or decrypt it while it's needed. Even using a hash (sha-256) of the foreign key alongside the encrypted foreign key in a specific column to be able to grouping and joining the data on my hashed foreign key (because of its deterministic nature).
What I'm looking for is other possible solutions for this kind of need. Is there any, or is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Why would you hash a foreign key? Usually, an INT or BIGINT is used for the primary key and foreign key, let's say 23. The hash of 23 will be different, but it will still point to the same records in other tables. What's the benefit?

in this case the key 23 is undetectable for some one who looks at the data, but for me, when i need to , lets  say perform a join query, i have the key, i can hash it again with my former used algorithm and compare the resulted hash with this hashed column of table or grouping data by this similar hash etc.

But why? The purpose of a foreign key is to connect records between different tables. If the primary key in A, let's say id 23, is used in B as a foreign key, you also store this value 23 in B. Imagine you hash 23 and you get xyz. It would still connect the same records in the same tables. There is no benefit in using an hash.

That looks like you are doing the wrong thing.
Foreign keys and primary keys should not be encrypted, because they don't carry any meaning as such.  If anything, encrypt those attributes of the user that could be used to identify him or her.  If you'd to encrypt the connection between a user and the associated entities, you would forgo the possibility to join tables in the database, and all efficiency and referential integrity would go out of the window.

thank you, this is exactly what my challenge is. by encrypting the foreign keys, i'll lose all the benefits of what we call "relational db" . but what you didn't mentioned, is what should i do to gain my purpose which is securing  and concealing relations ?

you mean i need to encrypt the data and not the relations? ya?

Exactly. If you don't encrypt the data, but encrypt the foreign keys, you will know all the names and addresses, just not who lives where. If you encrypt that data, you will know that somebody has three houses, but you don't know who and which houses. The latter clearly provides better security (and you don't have to sacrifice relational integrity).
